# What is proper MVC structure for embedding a custom view within another view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Thinking it over, this feels like a bit of a noob MVC question, but I can't come up with or find a definitive answer so I feel I should ask and get some clarity for myself.

I have a custom view that I created using a xib. It is going to be used in, currently, 4 other places in my app. Each usage has identical functionality, so I'm basically just creating a custom control object that I can reuse multiple times.

My "control object" consists of a UITextField, and two UIButtons.

The functionality I'm looking at implementing is, the first button will bring up a UIPicker and the 2nd button is essentially a done button and will just resignFirstResponder on the UITextField. As previously mentioned, this is consistent everywhere this will be used.

What I'm curious about is, is it ok for me to build this functionality directly into the custom UIView subclass since it is consistent behaviour for all instances of my control object? Or, do I need to create a custom UIViewController subclass to go along with it?

Currently, in my main UIViewController for my app I am creating instances of my custom UIView "control object" and treating them the same as any other control object. If I should actually be creating a custom UIViewController class to go along with it, well, I'll have more questions for another thread as to how I should be doing that (unless someone can direct me to a resource on this)

So far, searching the web has yielded nothing for me and from everything I've seen so far with iOS development in general, I've gotten the vibe that UIViewControllers are really only ever for a main, presentable view (that takes up the entire screen.. I might be missing some terminology for this).

My gut feeling is that no view controller is necessary in the scenario I'm describing, but I'd like to try to get some sort of confirmation, if possible.

Comment: As long as the functionality or logic inside the custom view isn't too complicated, doing it in the subclass ought to be fine. Your custom object should also have the capability to return whatever text is required on pressing the *done* button in a call back. As long as your data model is separate, from your `UIView` object, which seems to be true in your case, there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no silver bullet, so no approach is *absolutely right* or *absolutely wrong*. What you describe here is just a view that changes its states. So putting everything in your `UIView` subclass is completely OK. It also conforms to the KISS principle.

However, as far as I understand, and correct me if I'm wrong, the input of your custom view - the text and the picked value from the picker does not really affects the view itself, but the `viewController` it's attached to. So you need to pass that input to the hosting `viewController`. This can be achieved by protocol with a default implementation. So the handling of the input data is written only once, but can be attached to whatever `viewController` you want.

Comment: Great, thanks!

The text field does get passed back to the view controller, but the picker view only affects the view itself. The control object is for entering measurements, and the picker is to change the unit of measurement. It will just change the multiply value of an NSNumberFormatter.

I do have a delegate protocol set up already for the view so it can notify the controller when the value has been updated, then a method on the view itself to retrieve the current value. Sounds like I am on the right track then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based off of everything that you've said, I see no need for another view controller. I can see where the answer could be a little unclear considering that the actions are something that ViewControllers usually handle, but I think you'll be just fine letting your custom view handle this by itself.

If you add more functionality or more complex operations, then perhaps it is time to explore other options but for now I think the single view will be fine.